# If $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = F(s)$, then $\lim_{s \to 0}sF(s) = \lim_{t\to +\infty } f(t)$. provided the limits exist.

Tags: proof-verification, laplace-transform

$f$ is sectionally continuous and of exponential order. $F(s)$ denotes it's Laplace transform.

this is a stated theorem with no proof in 'Laplace Transforms - Murray R. Spiegel'.

my attempt at proving this :

$\int_{0}^{+\infty} f'(t)e^{-st}dt = sF(s) - \lim_{t\to0}f(t)$

taking the limit as $s \to 0$ on both sides we get :

$\lim_{s \to 0}\int_{0}^{+\infty} f'(t)e^{-st}dt = \lim_{s \to 0}sF(s) - \lim_{t\to0}f(t)$

now assuming I could move the limit inside the integral then I'm basically done. however I can't think of any justification. how do you justify my last step ?

Comment: The integration is done w.r.t $t$ and $s$ is a fixed _parameter_ (of the Laplace transform) independent of $t$, so shifting the limit with $s\to 0$ inside the integral is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, since $s$ is a fixed constant independent of $t$, shifting the limit inside the integral is perfectly valid.

In fact, this is known as the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem#Proof) and you can see the proof (given in the link) also does exactly this: writes the limit of integral as integral of limit.